# CMake can't find boost_python while compiling caffe

Tags: boost, cmake, caffe

I am compiling caffe and all other boost libraries were found except boost_python, but when i write a dummy CMakeList file calling

```
find_package(boost 1.46 REQUIRED COMPONENTS python)
```

it works fine (the above line is copied from caffe source `Dependencies.cmake`, with an additional REQUIRED directive added).

currently i have no idea about what happened inside caffe, any help on this? tell me if more information is needed.

Comment: Configure Caffe with additional `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` passed to CMake and show all lines in the configuration log which are about the finding Boost.

Comment: I finally get it compiled using the Makefile provided with the source and adding some additional include/library directory, although this is some kind of workaround. Caffe supports both make and cmake, but building by make is officially supported, so now i prefer make over cmake when compiling Caffe